# Apply Pandas series string function to the whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply the method `pd.Series.str.join()` to my whole dataframe

```
A         B
[foo,bar] [1,2]
[bar,foo] [3,4]
```

Desired output:

```
A      B
foobar 12
barfoo 34
```

For now I used a quite slow method:
`a = [df[x].str.join('') for x in df.columns]`

I tried

```
df.apply(pd.Series.str.join)
```

and

```
df.agg(pd.Series.str.join)
```

and

```
df.applymap(str.join)
```

but none of them seem to work. For extension of the question, how can I efficiently apply series method to the whole dataframe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There will always be a problem when trying to `joim` on lists that contain numeric values, that's why I suggest we first turn the into strings. Afterwards, we can solve it with a nested list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[['Foo','Bar'],['Bar','Foo']],'B':[[1,2],[3,4]]})
df['B'] = df['B'].map(lambda x: [str(i) for i in x])
df_new = pd.DataFrame([[''.join(x) for x in df[i]] for i in df],index=df.columns).T
```

Which correctly outputs:

```
A      B
FooBar 12
BarFoo 34
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[['foo','bar'],['bar','foo']],'B':[[1,2],[3,4]]})
#If 'B' is list of integers, else the below step can be ignored
df['B']=df['B'].transform(lambda value: [str(x) for x in value])
df=df.applymap(lambda value:''.join(value))
```

Explanation: applymap() helps to apply any function to each value of your dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
df_sum = df_sum.stack().str.join('').unstack()
```

I have a quite big dataframe, so `for` loop is not really scalable.